# Using $scope.$watch and still need $scope.$apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I've implemented a filedrop directive that puts the file dropped in ngModel.

```
<filedrop data-ng-model="file"></filedrop>
```

I'm using the following code in my controller:

```
    $scope.$watch('file', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $scope.parseFile(newVal);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(newVal);
        }
    }, false);
```

In $scope.parseFile Im actually parsing the XLSX:

```
    $scope.parseFile = function(file) {
        xlsxParser.parse(file).then(function(data) {
            console.log("Number of columns", data.datasheet[1].length);
            console.log("Number of rows", data.datasheet.length);
            $scope.validationErrors = [];
            $scope.brand = {
                items: []
            };
            $scope.dataItems = [];
            $scope.datasheetValidate(data.datasheet, $scope.brand);
            $scope.datasheetData(data.datasheet, $scope.dataItems);
            if ($scope.validationErrors.length == 0) $scope.validationErrors.push("Nice work, no validation errors");
            //$scope.$apply(function(){});
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I commented out the `//$scope.$apply(function(){});` in the body....

BUT, I need it in order to have my web page updated with the scope changes (e.g. show the `validationErrors`)

How come I need the `$scope.$apply`?

Comment: The only reason i see this happen if `xlsxParser.parse(file).then` is not a angular promise callback method.

Comment: You're actually right. It uses jQuery promise. May need to rewrite the borrowed code or accept the fact I have to explicitly call apply :-(

Comment: Great, adding it as a answer so that the question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter that you're using $scope.$watch. That doesn't help when you're calling `$scope.parseFile` from inside `reader.onload` callback, which is outside of Angular realm.

`$scope.$apply` should be used inside the callback itself:

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.parseFile(newVal);
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work.. Probably because of the comment mentioned by Chandermani. He's right, I may need to rewrite, it uses jQuery promises. Guess that happens when you're trying to reuse other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$watch` and `$scope.$apply` are complementary.

`$scope.$watch` registers a new watcher on the scope. Whenever there's a digest cycle, the watch function runs.

`$scope.$apply` *triggers* a digest cycle--that is to say, if nothing ever called `$scope.$apply`, no watchers would ever be run at all.

For built-in directives that deal with user input (`ng-click`, `ng-keydown`, etc.) and built-in services (`$http`, `$location`, `$timeout`, etc.), Angular calls `$scope.$watch` for you. However, any time you deal with asynchronous code that lives outside of these built-in directives or services, you must tell Angular that it should kick off a new digest cycle by calling `$apply` yourself.

As mentioned by Stewie, you should try to keep your `$apply` calls as close to the asynchronous operation as possible; in this case, it means using it at the very top level of the `onload` callback.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i see this happen if xlsxParser.parse(file).then is not a angular promise callback method.

And as confirmed by @Sander this indeed is not a angular promise, so option here is to keep using the existing $scope.$apply call.

Comment: I rewrote the code to not use promises at all, but callbacks, but problem remains :-(

Comment: You writing callback would not solve the issue, the callback still needs to be wrapped in `$scope.$apply` to switch into angularjs context.

Comment: You have any idea why? I don't mind leaving the "apply" in there, but I keep on puzzling why.... I'm eager to know